# Why my page scroll when I resize on my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, resize

I'm doing a dashboard and I am having a problem.

When I resize my window it scrolls by itself.

Everything is responsive but I do not understand why it scrolls.

Thanks you !

ps: I upload my site if you want check :)

https://edtmimi.000webhostapp.com/dashBoard/

[Before resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saOOm.png)

[After resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2CEi.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWGwk.png)

Comment: Does not look very responsive if you ask me.

Comment: @ptothep All my Item resize just my page scroll

Comment: Sorry I'm not really good in english I put bad title. (edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your profileScroll.js file to the code below.

When you resize your browser, the scroll position changes. Since you use this to animate and calculate the position for your pages, you need to recalculate them when resizing the window.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var delayInMilliseconds = 1;
    
    function updateScrollPosition() {
      if (window.scrollY != document.getElementById("homePage").offsetTop || window.scrollX != document.getElementById("homePage").offsetLeft) {
            window.scroll(document.getElementById("homePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("homePage").offsetTop);
        } else {
            document.documentElement.style.animationFillMode = "forwards";
            document.documentElement.style.animationDelay = "1s";
        }
        document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        updateScrollPosition();
    }, delayInMilliseconds);


    document.getElementById("profileButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("profilePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("profilePage").offsetTop);
    });

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("returnToHomePage").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("returnToHomePage")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("homePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("homePage").offsetTop);
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("mailButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("mailPage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("mailPage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("noteButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("notePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("notePage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("gameButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("gamePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("gamePage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("calendarButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("calendarPage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("calendarPage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("voiceButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("voicePage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("voicePage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("buyButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("buyPage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("buyPage").offsetTop);
    });

    document.getElementById("paramsButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.scrollTo(document.getElementById("paramsPage").offsetLeft, document.getElementById("paramsPage").offsetTop);
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      updateScrollPosition();
    });

});
```

But I would make it a bit more generic:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
const delayInMilliseconds = 1;

let currentPageId = 'homePage';

function scrollToPage(pageId) {
    currentPageId = pageId;
    window.scrollTo(document.getElementById(pageId).offsetLeft, document.getElementById(pageId).offsetTop);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    document.documentElement.style.animationFillMode = 'forwards';
    document.documentElement.style.animationDelay = '1s';
    document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';
    scrollToPage(currentPageId);
}, delayInMilliseconds);

let actions = [
    { buttonId: 'profileButton', pageId: 'profilePage' },
    { buttonId: 'mailButton', pageId: 'mailPage' },
    { buttonId: 'noteButton', pageId: 'noteButton' },
    { buttonId: 'gameButton', pageId: 'gamePage' },
    { buttonId: 'calendarButton', pageId: 'calendarPage' },
    { buttonId: 'voiceButton', pageId: 'voicePage' },
    { buttonId: 'buyButton', pageId: 'buyPage' },
    { buttonId: 'paramsButton', pageId: 'paramsPage' },
];

// Make sure you use `let` instead of `var`. The scope of `var` is global. 
for (let i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(actions[i].buttonId).addEventListener('click', function() {
        scrollToPage(actions[i]);
    });
}

// Check all document clicks, if the target has the class 'returnToHomePage' go back to home page.
// This way you don't have to loop over the buttons
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('returnToHomePage')) {
        scrollToPage('homePage');
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    scrollToPage(currentPageId);
});
});
```

Comment: You'll also have to do something similar for when the current position is an other page than the homepage.

Comment: Yes I am doing it!

Comment: You think I can do with getBoundingClientRect() method ?